# How to use semaphores correctly

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

I've been posed a problem along the lines of Santa's workshop where numerous things have to happen before presents can be delivered. One such requirement is that eleven elves successfully manufacture 100 presents. My main class looks like this:

```
public class Main {

    public volatile int toyList = 100;

    public int getToyList() {
        return toyList;
    }

    public void setToyList(int toyList) {
        this.toyList = toyList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main main = new Main();

        ...

        Elf elfOne = new Elf("Jim", main);
        Elf elfTwo = new Elf("John", main);
        Elf elfThree = new Elf("Eamonn", main);
        Elf elfFour = new Elf("Eoin", main);
        Elf elfFive = new Elf("Ronan", main);
        Elf elfSix = new Elf("Seamus", main);
        Elf elfSeven = new Elf("Rebecca", main);
        Elf elfEight = new Elf("Orla", main);
        Elf elfNine = new Elf("Tina", main);
        Elf elfTen = new Elf("Filly", main);
        Elf elfEleven = new Elf("Jess", main);


        ...

        elfOne.start();
        elfTwo.start();
        elfThree.start();
        elfFour.start();
        elfFive.start();
        elfSix.start();
        elfSeven.start();
        elfEight.start();
        elfNine.start();
        elfTen.start();
        elfEleven.start();

    }
```

and my Elf class looks like this:

```
public class Elf extends Thread{

    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(11);
    Random rng = new Random();
    String name;
    Main main;

    public Elf(String name, Main main){
        this.name = name;
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
                try {
                    semaphore.acquire();
                    makeToy();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    semaphore.release();
                }
        }
    }

    private void makeToy() throws InterruptedException{
        if (main.getToyList() != 0){
            if(rng.nextInt(99) <= 4){ //5% chance to fail
                System.out.println(name + " failed in making a toy!");
            }else{
                main.setToyList(main.getToyList() - 1);
                System.out.println(name + " created a toy! Toys remaining: " + main.getToyList());
            }
        } else {
            wakeSanta();
        }
    }

    private void wakeSanta() throws InterruptedException {

    }

}
```

A sample output I get is:

```
...
Eamonn created a toy! Toys remaining: 6
Jim created a toy! Toys remaining: 7
Eoin created a toy! Toys remaining: 8
Jess created a toy! Toys remaining: 9
Filly created a toy! Toys remaining: 0
```

The output I'd like to get is that it counts down sequentially with a random Elf from 100 to 0. Is it something as simple as my semaphore acquisition being in the wrong place or am I misunderstanding semaphores altogether?

Comment: The resource you are trying to protect is an int. Unless your assignment specifically asks for the Semaphore or the toy list will be converted into another structure later on, using an AtomicInteger would do the job, too. Without the complexity of managing the semaphore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your semaphore is not used correctly. A semaphore instance can grant a number of permissions.

- A thread can `acquire()` a permission - block until a permission is available and then decrease the number of available permissions.
- A thread can `release()` a permission - increase the number of available permissions.

In your code, each thread has its own semaphore with  `11` permissions. Firstly, being a means of synchronization, semaphores usually only make sense if they are shared by multiple threads. Secondly, if you want to make a resource (in your case `toyList`) fully mutially exclusive, the semaphore should only provide a single permission.

Think of it this way: In order to make toys, the elves need to use a machine. Now your scenario requires that only one elve can make a toy at the same time, which is equivalent to the workshop only having one toy-manufactoring machine. So - in code - you need to create the equivalent of a single machine: A single `Semaphore`-instance with only one permission. Okay, so let us put the `Semaphore` in the `Main`-class:

```
public class Main {

    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    // the rest of Main is kept the same
}
```

Now the elves need to get access to the toy-manufactoring machine, so instead of `semaphore.acquire()`, we use `main.semaphore.aquire()`. But if the machine is occupied when calling `run()` and never released, the first elf to start working won't ever let any other elf have the machine. So Santa put down some rules on how the machine is to be used:

- The machine must not be occupied unless an elf attempts to make a toy
- The machine must be freed once an elf (successfully or not) finished making a toy

So the code of `run()` and `makeToy()` changes as follows:

```
public void run(){
    while(true){ // sidenote: I would rearrange the nesting: Wrap the while-loop in the try-catch
        try {
            makeToy();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void makeToy() throws InterruptedException{
    main.semaphore.acquire();
    if (main.getToyList() != 0){
        if(rng.nextInt(99) <= 4){ //5% chance to fail
            System.out.println(name + " failed in making a toy!");
        }else{
            main.setToyList(main.getToyList() - 1);
            System.out.println(name + " created a toy! Toys remaining: " + main.getToyList());
        }
    } else {
        wakeSanta();
    }
    main.semaphore.release();
}
```

---

In case you are wondering about when to use a semaphore with multiple permissions, here an example:

Assume you have a resource that is read often and occasionally written. Because reading does not change the value (i.e., mutate the state), it is safe to have multiple threads read the value concurrently. Say we have `n` threads and a semaphore with `n` permissions. A thread must now acquire a single permission to read - meaning that all threads can read at the same time, but it must acquire all `n` permissions to be allowed to write - meaning while one thread is writing, no other thread can access the resource (neither to read nor to write).

---

Personally, I think of acquiring and releasing a semaphore with a single permission as a `synchronized`-block. However, note the important difference that user **Ralf** pointed out in a comment: A semaphore can be released by any thread regardless of which thread has actually acquired the permission. Semaphores are more expressive - with the downside that it is easier to use them wrong.

Comment: There is an important difference between a semaphore and a mutex/synchronized block: the lock placed by a synchronized block has thread-affinity, the semaphore has not. I.e. in the case of synchronized code only the thread that placed the lock can release it. But a semaphore can be decremented by one thread and incremented by another. So there is a quite semantic difference between the two.

Comment: @Ralf Thank you very much for this important information. Thinking about the similarities of semaphores and the `synchronized`-keyword has always helped me in understanding both, but it never before occurred to me that it is possible to implement a semaphore that is released by a different thread than the one acquiring it. For future reference I kept the analogy with an update based on your comment, but moved it to the bottom as it is a bit off-topic.

Comment: So what would happen in the case of acquiring a lock inside a synchronized block? Would this then mean that our semaphore would have thread-affinity? @Ralf

Comment: @FilipGrebowski, no a semaphore has no thread-affinity. If you decrement and increment a semaphore inside a synchronized block then it is guaranteed to be decremented and incremented by the same thread because it is done inside a synchronized block. But the semaphore would be completely pointless in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, a semaphore maintains a set of permits.Semaphore just keeps a count of the number available and acts accordingly.

Calling acquire() will blocks until permits is avaiable(more than zero) and then takes it(count down one). Each release() adds a permit.

You can consider sophomore as a guard who controls people's access on a door(the logic to which needs to control thread access). He has some keys(permits) to enter this door().

When a person(thread) need to enter this door, he needs a get a key(`acquire()`), or he waits until he gets the key(thread blocks) .After a person exits the door, he should  give back the key(`release()`) so that the other person can get.

So in your existing code, you have 11 keys for each thread to get, which does not make sense, since each person now have a separate guard who has 11 keys.

If you need to control that only one thread `makeToy()` at the same time. You should use semaphore with only one permit.

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
```

And this should be a public semaphore where thread shares, so you probably SHOULD NOT instantiate a  semaphore inside a thread.

You may try this :

```
    Main main = new Main();
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1,true);//Only allow one thread to enter,so totally one permit is avaiable, and fairness =true 
    Elf elfOne = new Elf("Jim", main,semaphore);//pass the semaphore to all the threads
    Elf elfTwo = new Elf("John", main,semaphore);
    Elf elfThree = new Elf("Eamonn", main,semaphore);
    Elf elfFour = new Elf("Eoin", main,semaphore);
   .....


public class Elf extends Thread{

    Semaphore semaphore;
    Random rng = new Random();
    String name;
    Main main;

    public Elf(String name, Main main,Semaphore semaphore){// need semaphore in constructors
        this.name = name;
        this.main = main;
        this.semaphore=semaphore;
    }
```

Here is the output of the changes code:

```
...
Filly created a toy! Toys remaining: 79
Eamonn created a toy! Toys remaining: 78
Eoin created a toy! Toys remaining: 77
Jess created a toy! Toys remaining: 76
Ronan created a toy! Toys remaining: 75
Jim failed in making a toy!
John created a toy! Toys remaining: 74
Seamus created a toy! Toys remaining: 73
Rebecca created a toy! Toys remaining: 72
...
```